# Structuring MVC with PDO and PHP 5

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

I am using PDO to make the connection to the DB.
I was wondering how should i structure it using the MVC pattern.

Currently i have it like this:

[/model/DatabaseConfig.php](http://pastebin.com/Xi9Gg31R)

[/model/DB.php](http://pastebin.com/uhPBq1R9)

[/model/Model.php](http://pastebin.com/BhiANSuH)

[/model/MySQLDB.php](http://pastebin.com/RD1Pxp77)

[/model/User.php](http://pastebin.com/ax8BhyQs)

[View/index.php](http://pastebin.com/1NNZKXSt)

What do you think about it?
Is it ok? Should i place DB, Model and MySQLDB in another subfolder?

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, the database itself is not a model, it's a library which all or most models use.

Comment: So, what would you recommend me? To place those classes in a library folder instead of in the model one?

Comment: I'd move model classes to their own directory, so they can be differentiated to system/base classes such as Model. Maybe `/model/tables/User.php`?

Comment: @Steve - as per my comment on Kasia's answer, I recommend trying Propel or Doctrine. Unless you're just doing this for educational purposes, you'll save yourself a ton of work by using stuff off the shelf. There's a link below if you're interested in seeing how easy Propel is to get started with `:)`

Comment: @halfer, i have considered it, but i need to create a new system fast and doctrine seems not to be so fast to understand.

Comment: I can't speak for Doctrine, since I've not used it; however Propel is simple to understand, imo anyway. It is well supported by auto-complete in the likes of Eclipse and Netbeans, which really helps. I appreciate it takes a little time to get used to any new library, but in general I think that is still faster than _writing_ a simple replacement. (And the replacement is rarely as simple as one originally intends, I find)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at DAO design pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object. It allows for the separation of Models and Database interface, which will be very useful if at some point you want to switch the database.

You might also want to read more about it in this article http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part-ii/

It's a matter of preference, but I would structure them in the following manner

```
Model/User.php 
DAO/MySQLDB/User.php 
DAO/MySQLDB.php (old DB.php)
Config/DatabaseConfig.php 
View/Index.php 
MySQLDB.php
```

`Model` would contain all the Model classes with Business Logic in them
`DAO` would contain all the generic database SQL scripts and connections
`Config` would contain all the configuration scripts
`View` all the views
Not sure what the `DB.php` does, so not sure where to place it.

Steve was asking in the comment about the difference between `Model/User.php` and `DAO/MySQLDB/User.php`, hope this example will illustrate it well

```
class Model_User
{
    public function hashPassword($password)
    {
        $salt = SALT_STRING;
        return hash("sha512", $password.$salt);
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
    $id      = (int) $id;
    $db_data = new MySQLDB_User();
    $db_data->getById($id);
    return $this;
    }
}
```

and

```
class MySQLDB_User
{
    public function getById($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` "
        ." WHERE `id` = \"" . $this->_db_connection>real_escape_string($id)
        . "\" LIMIT 1";
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $this->_parseRow($result);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Have a look at how the biggest frameworks structure their folders i.e. Zend Framework example is here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html

They usually thought long about the set up, and most of the developers are familiar with it, so if you have a new hire, they will be able to find their way around the custom built system quicker than they would otherwise.

Comment: I have read both of your links, but i still wondering how to structure my classes. I can create a DAO and a VO folder but... where do i place the DB, Model and MySQLDB clases ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Steve, I made some edits to the post with my suggestion :)

Comment: +1 for a good answer, though I tend to regard the separation of models and databases as something of a purist position. I made this point very recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11551405/472495), which may be of interest to @Steve. If you are just reading a table (say, a newsfeed) then this can come from any source type: a database, an XML source, etc. But at some point you'll be doing joins and where clauses in your controller, which in practise hardwires your code to a SQL database of some kind.

Comment: I've seen you have created two User.php classes. One as VO (persistent data) and the other to access the DB?
Then, you have in there two MySQLDB classes. Why is it? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: @Steve Model class would in this instance consist of business logic i.e. a function that creates a URL to a user profile and the DB class would contain all the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE statements if it's for MySQL. Model would initiate DB class and use it to fetch/save data, but any further modification would stay there. if you imagine that in the future you decide to move to another database, you just need to create adapters for another database, rather than worrying about the implications of that move on business logic. hope this helps

Comment: @halfer thanks for the link, I will have a read, always enjoy finding out other devs stance on the architecture :)

Comment: @Steve I added a code example that might illustrate it better

Comment: @KasiaGogolek - no worries. In relation to your splitting User into two classes to achieve database independence, I might be inclined to recommend using Propel or Doctrine here. That stuff is all working and tested - the only purpose to _rolling ones own_ is its educational value, imo. I wrote a [really trivial demo](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/02/some-pointers-on-propel-1-5/) ages ago, which may be useful.

Comment: couldn't agree more about using Propel or Doctrine!

Comment: Kasia, then... where do i place the VO classes?

Comment: @Steve VO is a J2EE pattern that I haven't seen used much in PHP I would set the values you require in Model/User.php

Comment: I am willing to understand Doctrine, i started trying it a week ago, but i need to know how to work without it too :) Thanks for all!

Comment: @KasiaGogolek do you have any open project or any link to any code where i can see a good implementation of MVC in PHP? Thanks.

Comment: @Steve you should have a look at Zend Framework, Kohana etc. They have been developed by a lot of people who know their stuff. Have a read through their documentation, and think about what would work for you and what wouldn't.